# Adding comma and dot separated values in PHP

Tags: php

The current application I'm building needs to let the user enter values like "3,040,400.00".

I noticed that PHP doesn't know how to add or substract values with that format?

How can I perform this operations keeping in mind that the user will enter values formatted as above?

For example:

```
$a = '3,040,400.00';
$b = '23,949.00';

echo $a - $b; // returns -20
```

Comment: Remove any commas before doing math on the values, e.g. with `str_replace`.

Comment: Numbers don't have a "format" in that sense.... strings may represent formatted numeric values, but aren't themselves numbers

Comment: Remove any commas before submitting them to your database. You can always reformat them later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply use `str_replace()` in order first to remove to commas inside the string. You cannot outright do arithmetic on them. Then after converting them properly you can use `number_format()` in the end. Consider this example:

```
$a = '3,040,400.00';
$b = '23,949.00';
$a = (float) str_replace(',', '', $a);
$b = (float) str_replace(',', '', $b);
$total = $a - $b;
echo number_format($total, 2, '.', ','); // should output : 3,016,451.00
```

[**Fiddle**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/0zjkYE)

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = str_replace(",","",$a);
```

same for b

for outputting your values you can use the php-function `number_format()`:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: That crossed my mind, but the result needs to be displayed in the same form, with commas and dot.

Comment: @Cosmin You should apply any rounding/formatting to numbers only at the point where you actually display the values

Comment: use this php function for your output formatting. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php